# Prevent fixed ratio items from overflowing flex container on cross axis when growing

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to fit 1x1 items (could be avatars) inside a flex row container of a predetermined ratio that can grow based on parents. Problem is that under a certain number of items, they overflow the container vertically (flex cross axis).

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3hv0bxuf/3/
HTML:

```
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="subitem">
          1
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="subitem">
          2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
div.container {
  margin-top: 40px;
  /* display: grid; */
  display: flex;
  /* grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; */
  /* grid-template-rows: 1fr; */
  /* align-items: center; */
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  display: flex;
  /* align-items: stretch; */
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  /* object-fit: contain; */
}
.subitem {
  /* width: 100%; */
  flex: 1 1 0;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Tried `display: grid` instead of flex, with same results.
I am expecting a structure that dynamically fits items on both axis without specifying px dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper container to fix the width and height and then use a flex to display your boxes (the flex container width will influence the value of `1fr` otherwise).
Here the wrapper is in green (with a padding to make it more visual), the height with `calc(100% - 10px)` has to be adapted depending on the padding.

```css
div.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: green;
}

div.sub-container {
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.item {
  display: grid;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
}
.subitem {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="sub-container">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="subitem">
            1
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="subitem">
            2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```